# Remap F1 to ESC (or meta) on 10.15.7 and emacs 27.1

Tags: emacs, keyboard, macos-catalina, remap

MacBook Pro running 10.15.7.  My beloved old external keyboard which emulates an IBM thinkpad (yes, with the pressure stick between g and h!) is starting to go.  I have a backup keyboard but alas: ESC is half the size and I keep hitting F1.   I wish to remap F1 to ESC.  The other mappings (e.g. CapsLock -> Ctrl) are straightforward and working using the `Settings->Keyboard->Modifier Keys` capability.

Far and away the biggest use case here is ESC as meta in `emacs`, so if there is an "easier" means to change F1 to meta *only* in `emacs` I am good with that too.

Comment: How did you achieve your "straightforward and working" mappings, and what have you tried so far for remapping F1?

Comment: The standard Modifier Keys Caps/Control/Alt swaps; post altered for clarity there.
I have examined various `(setq)' and permutations of `(global-set-key (kbd "<f1>") 'meta) but it seems to not do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if there is an "easier" means to change F1 to meta only in emacs I am good with that too.

Try this:

```el
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "<f1>") (kbd "ESC"))
```

Comment: ... and that's one I did not try but works like a charm.   emacs forever.   Many thanks.